# Smoke Simulation Vibrating

Tags: rendering, baking, smoke-simulation

Last week I started making a volcano that was starting to erupt. I've got some sparks and I made a nice smoke simulation. I clicked Bake All Dynamics and then rendered. The result was a nice volcano with sparks. The smoke, though...
It's hard to explain, but it's vibrating. I don't think smoke should do that.
I've google a bit for vibrating smoke, but I couldn't find anything except for actual blender that start smoking.
[This is the actual animation for anyone who would like to see it.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ixnfs8008tt08no/output_kc4G5j.gif)
Does anyone here have any idea what I may have done wrong and/or maybe some tips to speed up the baking and rendering process (it take way longer that I have time for).

[image]

Comment: Maybe you've put a noise modifier into location channel under the domain object? The whole domain object vibrates imho. You should post some screenshots of your objects setup or even share the .blend file to make it easier, it's a guess game otherwise.

Comment: Do you have a force-field in place?

Comment: I have one wind off to the side and one turbulence above the volcano.

Comment: I assume to wild turbulance (that one impacts smoke as well).

Comment: Hard to guess. Can you provide scene file? (You can upload file [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/))

Comment: I added the .blend file, but it's no use anymore. I turned on dissolve and rebaked and rerendered the thing and it's good now.

Comment: It seems that some of the baking frames were overwritten.. So baking all physics before render is very helpful

Comment: I suspect you have "Adaptive Domain" turned on... Have you tried to re-run the simulation without it?

Comment: Why would that be a problem, exactly? I always leave it on to save memory and space on my harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

To speedup rendering, you may render smoke, sparks and  volcano separately. Maybe you have accidentally rendered every 2nd frame? do the frames per seconds from the render settings match the video output FPS settings?

Comment: I know for sure that i haven't rendered every 2nd frame. I have 200 frames in my frames folder, which is how it should be. I usually render the frames and then stick them together later in another instance of Blender where I choose the fps.